# How to link local repository in the maven build process

Tags: java, maven, jar

How to point to a local repository in the maven build process. In that case I want to link directory with custom jars with the compilation and packaging.

1. Tried following "mvn compile  -Dmaven.repo.local=E:\Test\lib" but it doesn't use located jars for the compilation.
2. Is there way to include repository through maven pom.xml in the way we inject dependencies?

Comment: look at this http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-remote-repository-in-maven-pom-xml/ but this article show only how to add simple repo but not local repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the custom jars into your local repository (usually located under C:..User.m2\repository) via [maven-install-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar \
                         [-DpomFile=your-pom.xml] \
                         [-Dsources=src.jar] \
                         [-Djavadoc=apidocs.jar] \
                         [-DgroupId=org.some.group] \
                         [-DartifactId=your-artifact] \
                         [-Dversion=1.0] \
                         [-Dpackaging=jar] \
                         [-Dclassifier=sources] \
                         [-DgeneratePom=true] \
                         [-DcreateChecksum=true]
```

But i would suggest to install a repository manager (like Archiva, Artifactory, Nexus) and install those artifacts there. So you need to do the manual installation work only once and not on every developing machine.

The best way to configure several repositories is via the [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file and not in the [pom.xml file](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly pom.xml is for that purpose to maintain dependencies.. you can get more on [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Local Repository"?

If you mean a local Nexus / Artifactory you can use the Maven  sections in your settings.xml

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

If you mean the local repository cache (the .m2 dir) that should just work out-of-the-box.